# Shell-Using sed to Remove Subdirectories from a List

Tags: regex, shell, sed, subdirectory

I have a file like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
  /home/user/Directory1
  /home/user/Directory1/subdirectory1
  /home/user/Directory1/subdirectory2
  /home/user/Directory2
```

I want to get rid of any subdirectories. In other words, I want this to happen:

```
$ ./myprogram.sh
$ cat file.txt
  /home/user/Directory1
  /home/user/Directory2
```

I have tried reading in the first line and setting a string and then reading in each other line and using sed -i to remove the line if a substring of the new line the length of the first string matches. Anyway, it got unwieldy and did not work properly. Tell me if you want me to post the broken code here.

Also, the list is in alphabetical order, so that might or might not help.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
cut -d / -f 1-4 file | uniq
```

Output:

```
/home/user/Directory1
/home/user/Directory2
```

Comment: An alternative with grep, sed and bash which really searchs for substrings: `grep -Evf <(sed 's/.*/&.+/' file) file`

Comment: This is really great, but it would be a lot better for what I'm doing if I could do something about the 1-4 part. For example, if I had something like /home/user/Directory1/subdirectory1 as the lowest directory in my file, then this program would output /home/user/Directory1, which is a problem. Does that make sense?